# Issue appending domain name to URI in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

Our Google Analytics environment was setup with an append hostname to URI filter which would append as follow:

/cincinnatibell.com/ and example would be /cincinnatibell.com/discover

An IT developer overwrote our filter and caused an issue with the appending.
All of the pageview URIs were reset to /discover, /plans-and-pricing, etc. Instead of including the domain name

I am trying to restore it. Right now, I followed these instructions to append hostname to URI (https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2015/12/10/basic-google-analytics-filters-every-site/) however, I am now getting /www.cincinnatibell.com/discover

How do I remove the www. from the URI? I tried a Search and Replace to remove the www. from the hostname but that only changed the hostname, it didn't fix it for the URI as well

[July Data the way we want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYyNj.png)

[August Data messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBeMH.png)

[August Data with append hostname to URI, better but we want it the way July looked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnABN.png)

Answer (score 0):

The fix should be fairly easy. You just need to split the hostname into 2 parts, the `www.` and the `cincinnatibell.com` and then only extract the second piece.

```
Field A - Extract A: Hostname; ^(www\.)?(.*)
Field B - Extract B: {leave blank}; {leave blank}
Output to - Constructor: Hostname; $A2
```

The `?` checks if there is either 0 or 1 instances of `www.`, so if you have different versions of the hostname (one with the www, one without), this will match either.

The `$A2` extracts the second part of the hostname, anything after the `www.` (whether it's there or not).

You then use this extract to prepend to your `Request URI`.